# Change keys on ssh server

Tags: ssh, openssh

I just re-installes openssh server on my Linux, and I need to generate new keys, BUT I can't find anywhere how to do it?

When I'm searching they are only taking about keys to login, and how to create public keys.

but HOW do I change/replace the server keys?

Answer (score 3):

To regenerate the keys, you need to delete the old ones (or move them out of the way):

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_*_key{,.pub}
```

and then generate the keys. On Debian-based systems,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

and on other systems,

```
ssh-keygen -A
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the SSH host keys, your can usually regenerate these by reconfiguring the package:

Debian / Ubuntu based:

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssh-server

CentOS / Redhat based / generic:

$ sudo ssh-keygen -A